# How to display every man page available on a unix system

Tags: linux, unix, man

How can I display every man page available on a unix system?  I want to list them all in an easy manner without manually digging up all the search paths, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find $(find /usr /opt -name man -type d) -type f
```

Comment: If you are in the habit of installing things as an unprivileged user you may want to add `$HOME` to the starting paths; or if you are looking for every thing that *anybody* has installed add `/home`.